# Concatenate two different cell strings, based on ID using Allen Browne ConcatRelated()

Tags: vba, ms-access, concatenation

I'm trying to use the Allen Brownes ConcatRelated, but not sure if that is needed for this or not.

I have a database with pipes, and their ids, in this I also have a column with the amount of observations on a giving pipe. These observations are on the same pipe but in different rows. I would like to concatenate this into one cell.

To start of with I have two identical set up queries, with the same columns and types in them, these I join in a union query.

Then I want to create a query based on that Union where i concatenate the aforementioned rows.

Probably easier to show in a picture:
[image]

Union query is EksportOverblik, where I would like to concatenate the cells Antal observationer if they have the same delledning.

This is what I tried so far.

```
Concatrelated("Antal observationer fordelt på kriterie/type";"[EksportOverblik]";"DelledningsID = " & [DelledningsID])
```

Also tried

```
ConcatRelated("[Antal observationer fordelt på kriterie/type]";"[EksportOverblik]";"DelledningsID = " & [EksportOverblik].[DelledningsID])
```

and

```
ConcatRelated("[Antal observationer fordelt på kriterie/type]";"[EksportOverblik]";"DelledningsID";[EksportOverblik].[DelledningsID])
```

Basically all the ones with the same DelledningsID need to have their Antal observationer fordelt på kriterie/type concatenated into one.

I'm getting Error 3070: The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize '383' as a valid field name or expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed I had it right, but a dynamic parameterized query beforehand was the issue. Removed that and it works.